# Does order matter in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

All apologies for the noob question. Does the order variables etc are in affect how they are executed? Does it read left to right and down like a human and execute in order, or does it look at everything at once and execute based on priority, or some combination of both?

Comment: Yes. Look for operator precedence table.

Comment: Variables aren't "executed." *Statements* within a function, on the other hand, are executed in sequence.  This question is pretty vague.  If you have a question about a specific situation, you should ask about that and provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Look at operator table in official language tour for dart to know which operator precedes other one.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators

There are some operators where RHS is executed first (like assignment operator aka '=') and there are others where LHS is executed first (like '+', '&&' etc). If you are not sure which operator might execute first, try using brackets or use intermediate variables. It gives better readability to other developers without confusion.

Also,
Dart code is executed in procedural manner (line 1 would execute before line 2 unless async call is made). Learn more about it with EventLoop. More info at https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartasync---asynchronous-programming